# I want to add sin and other trigonometry functions in my JS calculator

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry

This "sin" function is not working properly. I don't know my mistake. I must be wrong somewhere but i am not getting it. Anyone can please correct by JS code for sin .
I have provided my HTML and JS code for the same.
Basically, when I press "sin" button, it will show me "NA" and after some small changes, it will show me "0" sometimes.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="calculator">
            <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>(</button></td>
                    <td><button>)</button></td>
                    <td><button>C</button></td>
                    <td><button>%</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button id="d">sin</button></td>
                    <td><button>cos</button></td>
                    <td><button>tan</button></td>
                    <td><button>DEL</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>7</button></td>
                    <td><button>8</button></td>
                    <td><button>9</button></td>
                    <td><button>X</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>4</button></td>
                    <td><button>5</button></td>
                    <td><button>6</button></td>
                    <td><button>-</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>1</button></td>
                    <td><button>2</button></td>
                    <td><button>3</button></td>
                    <td><button>+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>0</button></td>
                    <td><button>.</button></td>
                    <td><button>/</button></td>
                    <td><button>=</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Java Script**

```
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (item of buttons) {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        buttonText = e.target.innerText;
        if (buttonText == 'X') {
            buttonText = "*"
            screenValue += buttonText;
            screen.value = screenValue;
        } else if (buttonText == "C") {
            screenValue = ""
            screen.value = screenValue;
        } else if (buttonText == "=") {
            screen.value = eval(screenValue)
        } else if (buttonText == "DEL") {
            screen.value = screenValue.slice(0, -1)
            screenValue = screen.value

        } else if (buttonText == "sin") {
            var x = screen.value;
            x = x * Math.PI / 180;
            screen.value = Math.sin(x);
            screenValue = screen.value
        } else {
            screenValue += buttonText;
            screen.value = screenValue;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: where are you initiating `screenValue`?

Comment: Slightly OT,.  Assigning the same function handler to multiple click handlers is a good idea,.  But a point of note your code will actually be generating multiple function instances instead.  Only mention as it looks like that's what you meant to do.

Comment: Try with `var x = eval(screen.value);`. If there is an expresssion, that won't work in itself. Just type `"45"*Math.PI/180` and `"3*15"*Math.PI/180` in the developer console and you will see the difference.

Comment: @tevemadar It didn't work either.

Comment: @tevemadar Unless it's a toy project that nobody but the user is going to use, don't recommend eval to people...

Comment: @Keith Actually it's uglier in this case because OP ends up performing an if-else in the function body.

Comment: @Yashgupta  Try to debug it yourself first -- if you are not familiar with the developer console, you can still add some `console.log` to print out the value of `buttonText` and `x` at various points.

Comment: @user202729  Yes, I would avoid using big if else blocks too, but that wasn't the point I was making.

Comment: @user202729 the code already uses `eval()`, and it is a toy project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems working fine, added `screenValue = eval(screenValue)` when you press `=`

```js
let screenValue = "";
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (item of buttons) {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    buttonText = e.target.innerText;
    if (buttonText == 'X') {
      buttonText = "*"
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "C") {
      screenValue = ""
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "=") {
      screen.value = eval(screenValue)
      screenValue = eval(screenValue)
    } else if (buttonText == "DEL") {
      screen.value = screenValue.slice(0, -1)
      screenValue = screen.value
    } else if (buttonText == "sin") {
      var x = eval(screen.value);
      x = x * Math.PI / 180;
      screen.value = Math.sin(x);
      screenValue = screen.value
    } else {
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button>(</button></td>
          <td><button>)</button></td>
          <td><button>C</button></td>
          <td><button>%</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="d">sin</button></td>
          <td><button>cos</button></td>
          <td><button>tan</button></td>
          <td><button>DEL</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>7</button></td>
          <td><button>8</button></td>
          <td><button>9</button></td>
          <td><button>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>4</button></td>
          <td><button>5</button></td>
          <td><button>6</button></td>
          <td><button>-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>1</button></td>
          <td><button>2</button></td>
          <td><button>3</button></td>
          <td><button>+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>0</button></td>
          <td><button>.</button></td>
          <td><button>/</button></td>
          <td><button>=</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding a runnable snippet to your question, however as others point out, `screenValue` was missing initialization and that prevented the code to run here on StackOverflow.

After adding that line, `sin` starts working, with the glitch I described earlier.

```js
let screenValue = ""; // <- this is the new line
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (item of buttons) {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    buttonText = e.target.innerText;
    if (buttonText == 'X') {
      buttonText = "*"
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "C") {
      screenValue = ""
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "=") {
      screen.value = eval(screenValue)
    } else if (buttonText == "DEL") {
      screen.value = screenValue.slice(0, -1)
      screenValue = screen.value

    } else if (buttonText == "sin") {
      var x = screen.value;
      x = x * Math.PI / 180;
      screen.value = Math.sin(x);
      screenValue = screen.value
    } else {
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button>(</button></td>
        <td><button>)</button></td>
        <td><button>C</button></td>
        <td><button>%</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button id="d">sin</button></td>
        <td><button>cos</button></td>
        <td><button>tan</button></td>
        <td><button>DEL</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>7</button></td>
        <td><button>8</button></td>
        <td><button>9</button></td>
        <td><button>X</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>4</button></td>
        <td><button>5</button></td>
        <td><button>6</button></td>
        <td><button>-</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>1</button></td>
        <td><button>2</button></td>
        <td><button>3</button></td>
        <td><button>+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>0</button></td>
        <td><button>.</button></td>
        <td><button>/</button></td>
        <td><button>=</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can type numbers, press `sin`, and it works. You can even type `1`, `+`, `1`, `=`, `sin`, and it will show the result. However if you type `1`, `+`, `1`, `sin` (note the missing `=`), it will show `NaN`, that's what the suggestion with `eval()` can fix:

```js
let screenValue = ""; // <- this is the new line
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (item of buttons) {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    buttonText = e.target.innerText;
    if (buttonText == 'X') {
      buttonText = "*"
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "C") {
      screenValue = ""
      screen.value = screenValue;
    } else if (buttonText == "=") {
      screen.value = eval(screenValue)
    } else if (buttonText == "DEL") {
      screen.value = screenValue.slice(0, -1)
      screenValue = screen.value

    } else if (buttonText == "sin") {
      var x = eval(screen.value);    // <-- the other change
      x = x * Math.PI / 180;
      screen.value = Math.sin(x);
      screenValue = screen.value
    } else {
      screenValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = screenValue;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button>(</button></td>
        <td><button>)</button></td>
        <td><button>C</button></td>
        <td><button>%</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button id="d">sin</button></td>
        <td><button>cos</button></td>
        <td><button>tan</button></td>
        <td><button>DEL</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>7</button></td>
        <td><button>8</button></td>
        <td><button>9</button></td>
        <td><button>X</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>4</button></td>
        <td><button>5</button></td>
        <td><button>6</button></td>
        <td><button>-</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>1</button></td>
        <td><button>2</button></td>
        <td><button>3</button></td>
        <td><button>+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>0</button></td>
        <td><button>.</button></td>
        <td><button>/</button></td>
        <td><button>=</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can type `1`, `+`, `1`, `sin` too, and it will work.

Comment: try pressing this buttons 5 + 5 = + 5 =, result is not proper

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I'm not sure what's wrong with 15. On a side note this is a follow up to my comment from days ago, because OP indicated it did not work.